# WebStorm - restrict find usages by file type extension

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to restrict the file type extension for find usages?

For example, when performing find usages while using TypeScript it would be useful to only see usages found in `*.ts` files, the `*.js` files should be excluded:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use scopes here. In Settings/Scopes add a new scope with only .ts files included, then select your class, hit Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F7 (Edit | Find | Find usages settings) , select the scope above as a scope in 'Find Usages' dialog

Comment: Thanks. For my use case I added a scope with `file:*.ts` pattern. Is there any way to make that scope the default find usages scope?